# How to alphabetize the li's within each the respective section using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I have an html list similar to the following: list items within the groups.  I have destroyed several jQuery scripts at this point.  I can't get into the sections and just alphabetize the li's.  I have tried using :nth-child to get to the li's, but it doesn't work.  Could anyone provide some insight please?

Thank you in advance.

```
  <h3 id="teams-01">TEAMS</h3></div>
<div>
<h3 align="left">vangard</h3>
</div>
<ul>
<li class="prod-offering">Rates</li>
<li class="prod-offering">Portfolio</li>
<li class="prod-offering">Cases</li>
</ul>
<h3 align="left">Fedility</h3>
<ul class="prod-offering">Rates
<li class="prod-offering">Cases</li>
</ul>
<h3 align="left">McCoughlah</h3>
<ul>
<li class="prod-offering">Rates</li>
<li class="prod-offering">Portfolio</li>
<li class="prod-offering">Cases</li>
</ul>
<h3 align="left">BrownRock</h3>
<ul>
<li class="prod-offering">Portfolio</li>
<li class="prod-offering">Cases</li>
</ul>
```

> I have tried various os this, adjust the :nth to try pick only the li's:

```
$(function() { var $mylist = $("#list"); $mylist.children().detach().sort(function(a, b) { return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text()); }).appendTo($list); });
```

---

```
var mylist = $('#list'); 
var listitems = mylist.children('li').get(); listitems.sort(function(a, b) { return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase()); }) mylist.empty().append(listitems);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript sort DOM element alphabetically using innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32452852/javascript-sort-dom-element-alphabetically-using-innerhtml)

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]. ALso not exactly clear what expected results should be here with your multiple lists

Comment: Do you want to select all li's and alphabetize them or you want to select the ul's and alphabetize their li's?

Comment: Hi @ruleboy21 I want to select just the li's within each ul and alphabetize respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly use this code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#some-id ul').each(function() {
    $(this).children().detach().sort(function(a, b) {
      return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text());
    }).appendTo($(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="some-id">
  <div>
    <h3 align="left">vangard</h3>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li class="prod-offering">Rates</li>
    <li class="prod-offering">Portfolio</li>
    <li class="prod-offering">Cases</li>
  </ul>
  <h3 align="left">Fedility</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="prod-offering">Rates</li>
    <li class="prod-offering">Cases</li>
  </ul>
  <h3 align="left">McCoughlah</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="prod-offering">Rates</li>
    <li class="prod-offering">Portfolio</li>
    <li class="prod-offering">Cases</li>
  </ul>
  <h3 align="left">BrownRock</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="prod-offering">Portfolio</li>
    <li class="prod-offering">Cases</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much @ruleboy21, that was such smooth solution.